# How to slide on click element with Vue-Carousel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, carousel

I am happy to ask my first question today :) How to slide on click element with Vue-Carousel?

I would like to trigger slide on right with a single click on my input.
This is my code based on documentation:

```
<carousel id="demo_carousel">
  <slide class="slides_demo">
      <input type="button" @click="getNextPage()" value="Go" />
  </slide>
  <slide class="slides_demo">
      <p>This is next page</p>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

And this is my function:

```
  methods: {
    getNextPage:function() {
      if (this.currentPage < this.pageCount - 1) {
        return this.currentPage + 1;
      }
      return this.loop ? 0 : this.currentPage;
    }
  }
```

But the sliding doesn’t trigger. What I’ve done wrong? Should I create my own function?

Vue-Carousel documentation: (https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel)

Thanks for help :)

Comment: can you show the rest of your code? where are stored variables like currentPage or pageCount?

Comment: Hello @LimeInTheCoconut I use methods from Carousel module that I use: https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel/blob/master/src/Carousel.vue but I am not really sure that it applies...

Comment: well if you can recreate a runnable script: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ or a jsfiddle would be a great help to understand what's going wrong

Comment: @LimeInTheCoconut I've tried to apply this carousel as a library but it didn't worked :( Thanks anyway for your help my friend

Comment: codesandbox is probably a better place for vue codes: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: Thank you so much @A.Lau

Answer (score 3):

Okay guys, I found my solution by myself. Hope it can help people in the future :)

That is my code:

```
<div class="VueCarousel-inner">
<carousel id="demo_carousel">
  <slide class="slides_demo">
      <input type="button" @click="gotoSlide()" value="Go" />
  </slide>
  <slide class="slides_demo">
      <p>This is next page</p>
  </slide>
</carousel>
</div>
```

There was a div before, which class was "VueCarousel-inner". It creates an array with all carousels inside. This is why I had to specify "slider[0]" to target my slider.

And the function i've created in methods that triggers automatically the slide you want by side of screen:

```
gotoSlide: function(){
      let slider = window.document.getElementsByClassName('VueCarousel-inner');
      if (window.innerWidth < 810) {
        slider[0].style.transform = "translate3d(" + "-" + slider[0].style.flexBasis + ", 0px, 0px)";
      } else {
        slider[0].style.transform = "translate3d(-810px, 0px, 0px)";
      }
    }
```

And it is fully responsive :)

Thank you everybody for your help !

Answer (score 1):

There's a function `goToPage` if you want to go to next or any specific slide. You can use the below code if you set `ref="carousel"`

```
this.$refs.carousel.goToPage(this.$refs.carousel.currentPage + 1);
```

It'll slide to the next page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a property `navigateTo`

[image]